# Setting a YouTube video's yt:AccessControl using VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, youtube-api, gdata-api

How I can disable comments/rate in video using Visual Basic .NET ?

Basically, how can I set the [`yt:accessControl`](http://code.google.com/intl/pl-PL/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#youtube_data_api_tag_yt%3aaccessControl) element?

How make this request in VB .NET https://code.google.com/intl/pl/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_updating_and_deleting_videos.html#Updating_Video_Entry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to [update the information via an HTTP PUT](http://code.google.com/intl/pl-PL/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#Response_codes_updating_information), specifically, [using the video's id](http://code.google.com/intl/pl-PL/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Updating_Video_Entry).

Here is an example of an HTTP PUT (taken from the second link above) which shows what the request to update a video would look like:

```
PUT /feeds/api/users/USERNAME/uploads/VIDEO_ID HTTP/1.1
Host: gdata.youtube.com
Content-Type: application/atom+xml
Content-Length: CONTENT_LENGTH
Authorization: AuthSub token="AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN"
GData-Version: 2
X-GData-Key: key=DEVELOPER_KEY

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"
    xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">
    <media:group>
        <media:title type="plain">Yippee Skippy</media:title>
        <media:description type="plain">I am updating this 
            video.</media:description>
        <media:category 
            scheme="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat">
            People</media:category>
        <media:keywords>blastoff,rodeo,whiteboards</media:keywords>
    </media:group>
    <yt:accessControl action="comment" permission="allowed"/>
    <yt:accessControl action="commentVote" permission="allowed"/>
    <yt:accessControl action="videoRespond" permission="allowed"/>
    <yt:accessControl action="rate" permission="allowed"/>
    <yt:accessControl action="list" permission="allowed"/>
    <yt:accessControl action="embed" permission="allowed"/>
    <yt:accessControl action="syndicate" permission="allowed"/>
</entry>
```

Note the multiple `yt:accessControl` elements at the end indicating the permissions of the video being set.

Also note that you can set these permissions when uploading the video as well.

Comment: How i can do this in VB.NET ?

Comment: @hades: At it's core, the GData API is based on HTTP and XML, you simply have to send the correct HTTP request and XML.  Google provides a [.NET client](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/code.html#NET) that you can use but it isn't always up-to-date with the specification.  If it isn't, you can still issue the requests and process the responses using things such as `HttpWebRequest`/`HttpWebResponse`, along with `XDocument` (for example).

Comment: @hades: If I can, I will (but I doubt I'll have the time to flesh out a full example), but it's quite involved and the links I provided you with contain all the information you need to do it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET client library added support for yt:accessControl in rev. 1118:

http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/detail?r=1118

To update the entry, you have to retrieve it first, then edit its YouTubeEntry.AccessControls collection and, eventually, call Update.